# How do I see how much time is left until the next break while using Workrave?

Tags: linux

I'm using [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/) on Ubuntu 12.04 as a work break reminder and timer.  However, I can't see how to get it to display the time remaining until the next break.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Workrave wasn't starting, and it wasn't starting apparently because I was logged into my machine remotely using NoMachine and Workrave wasn't detecting any mouse or keyboard activity.

The solution that seemed to work for me was putting Workrave in reading mode, opening the preferences dialog, and then closing the preferences dialog.  Now the countdown timers appear in the task bar and Workrave is issuing reminders.